# How to unlock my iphone 6+ after factory reset in Iran?

Tags: iphone, unlock, restart

I'm living in Iran and Apple does not provide direct support here. I had to factory reset my phone due to some problems and after that my sim card is not recognized any more. It seems (some service guy said) that the phone is locked to some operator abroad (I don't know which, I don't know how to find out, and I don't know if knowing it can do any good). Anyway, I have no idea how it was working during past 4-5 years but I can no longer use it with any iranian operator. Does any one have a clue what to do?

Comment: How did you acquire the iPhone? - You should contact the place you've bought the device - if the product is locked to a foreign operator, that sounds quite odd if you bought it locally.

Comment: Many things are odd in this regard in Iran. We are under toughest sanctions. I bought in in local market but I don't know how they have acquired it for retail in Iran. Apple provides no direct sales or service to Iran.